# Some Elastic fields DSL query searchable and some not

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elastic Search 6.8.1 and Dynamic Mapping.  I have one document in the index now, and am testing out searching on various fields.  I make a post to `http://localhost:9200/documents/_search` and send a DSL query

```
{
    "query": 
        {"bool":{"must":{"term":{"name": "item2"}}} }
}
```

and I get the document I expect:

```
{
    "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 0.2876821,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "documents",
                "_type": "document",
                "_id": "nRMOs5DZg",
                "_score": 0.2876821,
                "_source": {
                    "freeform": "DEF",
                    "name": "item2",
                    "url": "s3://mybucket/key",
                    "visible": true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, I want to make sure that I can search on the "freeform" field by changing the query to

```
{
    "query": 
        {"bool":{"must":{"term":{"freeform": "DEF"}}}   }
}
```

This results in no hits and I can't understand why.

[EDIT]
Here is the dynamic mapping

```
{
    "documents": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "document": {
                "properties": {
                    "freeform": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "url": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "visible": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1564776393764",
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "2er2TF-ySEKgk6gd32K6Ig",
                "version": {
                    "created": "6080199"
                },
                "provided_name": "documents"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to answer without seeing your mapping, but my guess would be this:

The dynamic mapping tries to guess the data type to assign to your fields; the default for string fields is the [`"text"` data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html), which means their value is *analyzed* and stored as a list of normalized terms, which is useful for free-text search. The string `"item2"` happens to survive this analysis unchanged, but `"DEF"` would be analyzed to `"def"`.

Since you're using a `term` query, the queried term doesn't go through the same analysis process, so you have to query using the analyzed term in order to match the document.

Try searching for `"def"` instead of `"DEF"` to test this hypothesis. Also, take a look at the automatically-generated mapping for your index and you'll see which data type each field was mapped to.

If this is indeed the case, you can do one of several things:

- If you want exact-string matching: change the mapping from `text` to `keyword` (you can control dynamic mapping using [Dynamic Templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html)); or alternatively search using the `keyword` sub-field which is created automatically for you by searching against `freeform.raw` instead of `freeform`.
- If you want "free-text" matching: use a `match` query instead of a `term` query so both the input and the document value undergo the same analysis (but make sure you understand how analysis and match queries work).

Comment: You are spot on, Avish.  Searching for "def" yielded a hit as well as a "match" query.  Thanks!